# Maximum term of (a + b) ^ n

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I would like a demonstration of the fact below.

Being given real numbers **a** and **b** (nonzero) and a positive integer **n**, the order **p**, that occupies the maximum term (in absolute value)
 of the development of power (a+b)^ n, according to decreasing powers of **a** is given by:

**p = 1 + integer part of [|b|(n+1)/(|a|+|b|)]**

When **n** is integer, there are maximum two terms: those of order **p** and **p-1**.

**|a|** and **|b|** are the modules of the numbers **a** and **b**, respectively.

Already, very grateful.

Paulo Argolo

Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(k)=C_n^k |a|^{n-k} |b|^k$.

Then $f(k+1)/f(k)=\frac{|b|}{|a|} \frac{n-k}{k+1} > 1$ iff $k<\frac{|b|(n+1)}{(|b|+|a|)}-1$, so $f(k)$ is increasing until $k=I\left(\frac{|b|(n+1)}{(|b|+|a|)}\right)$ where $I$ denotes the integral part.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not understand your resolution. The notation used is very confusing to me. I have difficulty with the symbols used.
Even so, many thanks

Comment: Maybe the notation $C^k_n$ is confusing you, it is also written $\binom{k}{n}$ and equal to $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.
To better understand the proof you can also do the case $a=b$, where only the binomial coefficients "count".

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}$, not $\binom{k}{n}$.

Comment: I needed to correct the statement. There were errors.

Answer (score -1):

Every positive integer is of the form 3k-2,3k-1, or 3k.

1. If n is of the form 3k-2, then ak has the maximum value
2. If n is of the form 3k-1, then ak = a[k+1] have the maximum value.
3. If n is of the form 3k, then a[k+1] has the maximum value.

It's not hard to prove each of those.  Write out the terms
with the factorials and powers of 2 for positive j<=k and prove: 
a[k-j] < ak {and/or a[k+1]}  and ak {and/or a[k+1]} > a[k+1+j]

Edwin McCravy

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I am sorry to tell you that you got off to kind of a bad start. Mathematically, your formatting is nonstandard, and the end result is quite different than the other answer which is well-justified. Also, you should not sign your name at the bottom of your posts; all of your posts come with a signature in the form of a link to your user page.